# re.form specifying one random effect but not the other

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, hierarchical-bayesian, stan

I have fitted a multilevel model using `stan_lmer` that has two sets of varying intercepts, one for categories and one for subjects. The code essentially looks like this:

```
outcome ~ predictor + time + (1 + predictor + time | category) + (1 | individual)
```

I would like to use `posterior_predict` to make predictions for specific category levels without having to specify individuals. I understand that you can instruct the predict function to avoid conditioning on any group terms by using `re.form=NA` or `re.form=~0`, however, what if I want to condition on one group term but not the other?

In this case, I want to make predictions for specific categories but not specific people and I am hoping there's an easy way of doing this that doesn't involve coding everything up from scratch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a formula for `re.form` that includes the parts that you want to condition on and integrates over the parts you don't want to condition on. It would be something like

`posterior_predict(foo, re.form = ~ (1 + predictor + time | category))`